# Running/Compiling a standalone dart file

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a dart standalone file, which calls the vector_math library. Upon trying to run the file, I get `Error: Could not resolve the package 'vector_math' in 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart'.`

I have tried `dart pub global activate vector_math` and `dart pub get vector_math` but it yielded the same same results.

Wondering if it is possible to work with just the .dart file, without starting a project with pubspec.yaml, etc? Will manually importing the package work, and how to do that? Initially wanted to just compile the .dart file for distribution (it's supposed to be a client to connect to a docker service). Thanks!

Comment: You need a `pubspec.yaml` file to specify the package dependencies.  If you want a standalone file that you can redistribute, you perhaps can try distributing the compiled binary.